# I can not connect to mongodb container with mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, mongodb-compass

Here is my docker-compose file

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb_container_gold_jar
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: haolamongodb
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: haolamongodb1210
    volumes:
      # named volumes
      - mongodb_gold_jar:/data/db
      - mongoconfig_gold_jar:/data/configdb
```

And here is my connection string: `mongodb://haolamongodb:haolamongodb1210@127.0.0.1:27017/root`.

I also try to use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` but it still does not work

the error message:
[image]

I have searched a lot but still got stuck on this, so pls help me figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I edited as your feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
My connection string is missing the `authenticationDatabase`.

I tried to connect with mongosh and succeeded.

```
docker run -it --rm --network server_default mongo \ 
mongosh --host mongodb_container_gold_jar \
 -u haolamongodb -p haolamongodb1210 --authenticationDatabase admin \
 root
```

so the connection string should be
`mongodb://haolamongodb:haolamongodb1210@127.0.0.1:27017/root?authSource=admin`